# ESLint Error : Prefer using arrow functions over plain functions prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I have these lines of code in one of my files. Running `ng lint` resulted in error "Prefer using arrow functions over plain functions  prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions" where I have the code `close(result: any)`, as shown below.

```
providers: [
   { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: { close(result: any): void {} } 
]
```

How can I rewrite that section to avoid this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should look like this

```
useValue: { close: () => {} },
```

but you can make it a spy, so then you would have an option to assert it

```
useValue: { close: jasmine.createSpy('dialogClose') },
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei.